# On the fly error reporting in PHP

Tags: php

When our site used to be on IIS hosting with PHP installed, I had error reporting set to E_NONE and was able to turn it on temporarily by using:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

That command seems to no longer work now that we are on Linux/Apache hosting.  I have tried purposely sending bad commands to the server and I get no errors reported.

What am I doing wrong?  Is there any other way to temporarily turn on error reporting without having to edit the php.ini each time?

Comment: IMHO, this sort of stuff is best set server wide (dev or prod) in your php.ini file.  I really love when people do file specific error display, it just creates a mess.

Comment: If I do it on the server, then it displays on the entire site.  By adding it to the page, it only displays on that page.

Comment: Here is the full list http://php.net/manual/fr/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can change error reporting to `E_ALL` using the following line:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Try adding that to the file.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to turn on all errors is:

```
error_reporting( -1 );
```

This is better than E_ALL, as E_ALL doesn't actually mean all errors in all versions of PHP (it only does in the most recent). -1 is the only way to ensure it's on in all cases.

Comment: Update: As of PHP 5.4 E_STRICT is now included in E_ALL, which now encompasses all error classes.

In my opinion E_ALL is generally better than -1.  This gives future PHP versions the option to introduce experimental new classes of error and to not have them trigger scripts based on E_ALL until a future version (like with E_STRICT back in PHP 5.x - 5.3).

Answer (score 3):

I just had to do this in one of my scripts.  DOMDocument warnings were killing my logs.  So, here's what you do:

```
// First, grab a copy of the current error_reporting level
// while setting the new level, I set it to zero because I wanted
// it off - but you could easily turn it on here
$erlevel = error_reporting(0);
// Then, do stuff that generates errors/warnings
// Finally, set the reporting level to it's previous value
error_reporting($erlevel);
```