# 'if variable equals variable echo this' causing white screen

Tags: php

Basically I have a select box with the values from a dataset, what I need to do is say select the one that is equal to the value of another field in the dataset. Here is the code, many thanks in advance for your help :-)

```
<option value="<?php echo $row_menucats1['id'] ?> " 

<?php 

$cats1 = $row_menucats1['id'];
$cats2 = $row_options['sub_cat_id_link'];

if ($cats1 == '$cats2') { 

echo 'selected' 
}

?> >
```

Comment: A white screen is usually indicative of a syntax or other fatal error. Activate error reporting to get meaningful error messages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [On the fly error reporting in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720351/on-the-fly-error-reporting-in-php)

Comment: Your second variable (`$cats2`) is also in quotes. Remove the quotes.

Comment: @Pekka Many thanks for your comment, however my post does not relate to error reporting so therefore is not a duplicate.

Comment: `echo 'selected'` **;** Semicolon missing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simple syntax  error. You need a semicolon after your echo statement:

```
echo 'selected';
```

Also your if statement: if `($cats1 == '$cats2')` needs to be:

`if ($cats1 == $cats2)`

The current way you have it, it is an actual string.

To turn on [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) you can add: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: Would it not be infinitely more useful to teach the OP how to activate error reporting?

Answer (score 4):

You missed a semicolon:

```
echo 'selected'; // <-- here
```

In future you should turn on error reporting or view your error log. The white screen indicates a 500 internal server error which in this case means a PHP fatal error.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: Would it not be infinitely more useful to teach the OP *how* to activate error reporting?

Comment: @Pekka, absolutely, I was adding that as you commented :)

Comment: Give a man a fish and he eats for a day, teach him to fish and he eats for life :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's causing a white screen, you should enable error reporting. Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Also read this:

```
<option value="<?php echo $row_menucats1['id'] ?> " 

<?php 

$cats1 = $row_menucats1['id'];
$cats2 = $row_options['sub_cat_id_link'];

if ($cats1 == $cats2) {  // '$cats2' is just a string, $cats2 is a variable

echo 'selected'; // You missed a semi colon here
}

?> >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          <option value="<?php echo $row_menucats1['id'] ?> " 

          <?php 

                $cats1 = $row_menucats1['id'];
                $cats2 = $row_options['sub_cat_id_link'];

                 if ($cats1 == '$cats2') { 

                  echo 'selected'; //semi colon is missing
              }

          ?> >
```

Please notice comment mentioned in above code snippet.It was syntax error of semi colon missing in executable statement.Accoring to syntax rules for PHP every executable statement must end with semicolon.